# Marf Audio Analysis : Where can I find data for SpeakerIdent app?

Tags: java, wav, audio-analysis

I am using SpeakerIdentApp of marf for audio analysis . 
I wanted to explore it with more data other than provided by speakerIdentApp . 
I tried with some of the wave files at : http://www.wavsource.com/ but those files are not supported by marf .

```
nullwave is not 16 bit file
```

Then a tried SOX to covert the files into 16-bit .But the files are MP3 encoded and it doesn't support mp3 encode wav file .

**So my Problen is to find data which is supported by marf 16-bit wave files .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marf Only Support

```
bit Rate = 16-bit 
sampling rate = 8000Hz
```

One may find training sample from Marf Site With SpeakerIdentApp .[Samples](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/marf/SpeakerIdentApp-training-sets-0.3.0-devel-20050730.tar.gz?download)

But the problem is that the samples are not good with real world entities .

So One may Download any Wav files . Then the person has to convert that file to wav 16-bit 8000HZ

```
may use to convert ->  Ubuntu : Sound Converter
```